# Why I am always receiving data on the server side of a socket in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, segmentation-fault

After opening a connection between client and server, I need to handle any write command sent to the server using the command `read();` (i.e. when the client `write();` the server should `read();` right away).

It sounds to be a trivial problem. Firstly, I sent 58 bytes from the client. But, I am always receiving huge amount of data on the server side. Here you could find just the relevant part of code:

```
int sockfd, newsockfd;//, n0,n1,n2;
socklen_t clilen;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int reuse=1;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0)
    cerr << "ERROR opening socket"<< endl;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&reuse, sizeof(int)) == -1)
    cerr << "ERROR on reusing port"<< endl;
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(iport);
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    cerr << "ERROR on binding"<< endl;
cout << "Listening on port: "<< iport<< endl;
listen(sockfd,1);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
if (newsockfd < 0)
    cerr << "ERROR on accept" << endl;

while (1) {
    size_t msgSize=0;
    int n = read(newsockfd,&msgSize,sizeof(size_t));
        cout << "Breakpoint " << msgSize<< endl;

    // Reading bytes size from socket until 10MB
    if ( n> 0 && msgSize< 10485760) {
        byte bytes [msgSize];

        if (read(newsockfd, bytes, msgSize) > 0) {
            char ip [16];

            memset (bytes + msgSize, '\0', MSGMAXSIZE - msgSize - 1);
            if (read(newsockfd,ip,15) > 0) {
                string cIP = (string)ip;
                //cout << "Sender Ip: " << cIP << endl;
                process p = currentView.getProcess(cIP);
                message m(bytes,p);
                cout << "*************************" << endl
                     << "Message received:"  << endl
                     << "*****************" << endl;
                m.print();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result i got:

```
Listening on port: 4444
Connected to: 127.0.0.1:6666
Breakpoint 58
*************************
Message received:
*****************
Message text: I am trying to send a message
Message size: 58
Message sender: 127.0.0.1
Message stability: 0
**************************************************

Breakpoint 825634866
Breakpoint 808600630
Breakpoint 842478647
Breakpoint 959854903
Breakpoint 926303542
Breakpoint 876032050
Breakpoint 808601142
Breakpoint 892744503
Breakpoint 875971894
Breakpoint 825634866
Breakpoint 1144401970
Breakpoint 859256118
Breakpoint 825635639
Breakpoint 892745526
Breakpoint 775369265
Breakpoint 774909488
Breakpoint 14897
Segmentation fault
```

And here you could find the relevant part of code from the client side:

```
while (1)
    {
    if (!bufferMsg(m)) break;
    }

bool bufferMsg(message m) // Sends a message (m) to a process (p)
{
    mtx.lock();
    if(fifoBuffer.size() < 5)
    {
        fifoBuffer.push_back(m);
        size_t sizeMsg = m.getHeader().sizeMsg;
        byte * bytes = m.getBytes();
        if (!write(sendsockfd,&sizeMsg,sizeof(size_t)) || !write(sendsockfd,bytes,sizeMsg) || !write(sendsockfd,(char*)m.getHeader().sender.getIp().c_str(),strlen(m.getHeader().sender.getIp().c_str())))
        cerr << "ERROR writing to socket"<< endl;
        mtx.unlock();
        return true;
    }
    else{
        mtx.unlock();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here you could find the header of the message:

```
typedef struct HeaderType {
    size_t sizeMsg;
    process sender; // The header.sender process
    //view currentView; // the Current view
    //iClock C; // reserved for later use
    bool stability; // reserved for later use
}HeaderT;
```

PS: The terms `message` and `process` are some classes which I already created but are out of our concern.
Please feel free should you need more clarification or information.

Comment: What is msgSize and, if you want to see how much data was received on each call, why are you printing it out instead of 'n'?

Comment: '825634866' as bytes received is obviously bogus.

Comment: msgSize is not used to recognize the size of the received text. It's the size sent by the client. Actually, I need to compare it with the received size later.

Comment: Do you know about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) ? It is useful (e.g. to detect what is readable or writable)...

Comment: man read: 'Upon successful completion, read() and pread() shall return a non-negative integer indicating the number of bytes actually read' - you NEED this returned value on every read, not just to detect errors by comparing to 0, but to indicate exactly how much data was read from the streaming socket.

Comment: Yes, of course it is bogus

Comment: Dear @BasileStarynkevitch, I have just one file descriptor/ one connection. As you could notice listen(sockfd,1);

Comment: OK, so your protocol has a header that indicates the length of the following data.  That would have been good to know in your question, rather than having to dig it out of the code.

Comment: Yes @MartinJames, I have a header in the 'message' class. But, I don't think it's useful.

Comment: Do server and client have the same endianness?

Comment: '825634866' in hex is '31363032' - which looks suspiciously like ASCII numerics from a data buffer overflow.

Comment: Server and client are in fact two ports on the same server. I am working with loopback.

Comment: Oh, OK, nix the endianness for now.

Comment: :D I would like to thank you @MartinJames so much. You are really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I have the impression you think that client side write should be blocking and waits until the data is eaten up by the server. The OS is free to deliver as many bytes as it likes on a TCP stream.
- You have a lot of if `if(read(newsockfd, bytes, msgSize) > 0)` in your code where you seem to silently assume that the read either fails completely or delivers exactly the amount of data you're waiting for. That doesn't need to be the case.

This:

```
 if ( n> 0 && msgSize< 10485760) {
        byte bytes [msgSize];
```

is dangerous since the byte array (which I assume is a typedef) gets allocated on the stack and I assume no OS on the planet accepts a 10MB local variable. But I might be wrong or even modern compilers start to silently allocate it on the heap. It's the top candidate for your segfault the first time msgSize <10MB. Better do something like:

```
std::auto_ptr<byte> bytes(new byte[msgSize]);
```

For your read in of msgSize better do something like:

```
int n = 0;
int nn = 0;
while((nn=read(newsockfd,((char *)&msgSize)+n,sizeof(size_t)-n)>0 
   && n<sizeof(size_t)) {
 n+=nn;
}
```

On the client site you do something like:

```
write(sendsockfd,(char*)m.getHeader().sender.getIp().c_str(),strlen(m.getHeader().sender.getIp().c_str())
```

To transfer something like an IP (I assume a string like 88.1.2.250) But on the server side you read it like:

```
read(newsockfd,ip,15)
```

which doesn't need to fit each other. That would lead to a frame shift in your read and the next msgSize is bogus. May I assume the the first msgSize you ever read is correct ? Under the assumption that the first read actually delivers sizeof(size-t).

Comment: 'Under the assumption that the first read actually delivers sizeof(size-t)' - yeah, also endianness...

Comment: @MartinJames Absolutely right but I silently assumed that this is a small test setting were difference in endianness isn't an issue. The dump tells me he's connected tp 127.0.0.1, but - yes - he should read about [htonl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) and others.

Comment: Those big numbers are VERY suspicious:)  In hex, they nearly all look like ASCII numbers, (0x30-0x39).

Comment: @Oncaphillis, as for the 10MB, you are right. I replaced 10485760 by 10240 (i.e. 10MB by 10 KB) and I got rid of huge numbers. But I now get 'Breakpoint 49' and receive just two messages out of 5. Thank you very much. I will review my code and I'll be back in few minutes.

Comment: @user4231164 Did you repair your read(fd,ip,15) ? Your **breakpoint** only reports the current msgSize. I don't know if that makes sense for your application. It's way smaller then <800MB isn't it ?

Comment: @Oncaphillis, you are right too regarding the ip. Thank you very much. I will use other technique (sending the ip size before it) right?

Comment: Or just transfer it as a fixed set of 4 bytes. It's always the same size. It's endianess neutral and most compact. Only works for Ipv4 though.

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t msgSize=0;
int n = 0;
do{
    int t=read(newsockfd,((char*)&msgSize) + n, sizeof(size_t) - n);
    if(t<0)
        continue; //if no data is available (in nonblocking mode, or on timeout)
    if(t==0)
        break; //connection closed
    n+=t; //increase counter n by the amount actually read
} while(n<sizeof(size_t));
cout << "Breakpoint " << msgSize<< endl;

// Reading msgSize bytes from socket until 10MB
if ( n> 0 && msgSize< 10485760) {
    byte bytes [msgSize];
    n=0;
    int t;
    while((t=read(newsockfd, bytes + n, msgSize - n)) > 0 //if something was read
        && (n+=t)<msgSize //and the total is below msgSize, we continue reading
        || t<0)  //or when there is no data available, we will give it another attempt
    {
    }
    if(t>0){
        cout << "successful: " << n << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "only " << n << " of " << msgSize << "read" << endl;
    }
}
```

Tricky parts explained:

```
((char*)&msgSize) + n
```

This casts the **pointer to size_t** to a **pointer to char** and **+ n** increments the pointer by **n**-times the size of the type it points to.

```
(t=read(newsockfd, bytes + n, msgSize - n)) > 0
```

An assignment returns the assigned value. It has to be inside brackets, as without brackets the boolean result of the **>** comparison would be assigned to **t**.

Sidenote:

You should not send the raw binary representation of an integer value to another computer. The sender might uses a MSB byte order while the recipient could be using LSB. You should use the methods provided to convert from host byte order to network byte order. They are called **htonl** and **ntohl** (h:host, to:to, n:network l:long [4 bytes]).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I will keep it as reference. Indeed, I need to continuously write()/read() data. I don't want to read 10MB once.